# How to hide desktop until application starts fullscreen

Tags: lubuntu, startup, chromium, kiosk

Using Lubuntu 18.04.1.  I am running an application on startup from ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart.  This application uses node.js to start a Chromium browser full screen in kiosk mode, and must run with user privileges.  This is basically a kiosk with touchscreen.  The problem is the desktop is visible for about 3 seconds before the application starts, allowing the user to interact with the desktop.  Is there a way to hide the desktop while my application is starting?

Comment: Tried starting my app from /usr/share/xsessions/Lubuntu.desktop with the command Exec=/bin/bash <path to my startup sh> instead of Exec=/usr/bin/lxsession ... Wind up with Chromium filling the left half of the screen but offset down and right by about 8 pixels, also cut off at the bottom by about the same.  Behind Chromium is a terminal window that I can't get to.  I get a strange X cursor when I move to the right side of the screen, which is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the browser and nothing more, I would propose writing a [custom startup script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
exec your_chrome_call
```

This way you (after you (automatically?) log in) you will get a blank screen, with no possibility to interact and after that the fullscreen chrome

Comment: No, it's running a node application that starts Chromium as the UI.  Yes, it does auto-login.  I will investigate using an X session script to start my application.